# ASP.Net MVC Routing Issue..Again

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I don't know whether I'm just stupid (don't answer that!) or I'm fighting MVC routing but I have another problem.

In my Controller I do a RedirectToRoute("ErrorRoute") which renders a 404 View which has a MasterPage.

In the MasterPage I have a top navigation which has links such as /homepage and /news but when I am in the 404 View the navigation is /error/homepage and /error/news.

I have changed my route in Global.asax from this

```
routes.MapRoute(
             "ErrorRoute",                      // Route name
             "Error/Error404",                // URL with parameters
             new { controller = "Error", action = "Error404" }

             );
```

to this

```
routes.MapRoute(
             "ErrorRoute",                       // Route name
             "Error/Error404",                  // URL with parameters
             new { controller = "Error", action = "Error404" }
             , new { action = "Error404" }
             );
```

to see if that would help but I get a "No route in the route table.." error when I call RedirectToRoute

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your Links ActionLinks?

Use this:

```
Html.RouteLink("Link Title", new { controller="Home" action="Action" });
```

**EDIT**

Oh, Add a new Route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
             "homePage",                      // Route name
             "homePage/",                // URL with parameters
             new { controller = "Home", action = "HomePage" }
             );
```

And repeat for news

**ANOTHER EDIT**

After reading the comments again, if your menu is on every page, what you should be is create a base controller:

```
public class MyBaseController : Controller
{
    return ViewData["menu"] = List<MenuClass>;
}
```

Then all your Controllers (home, error) inherit this:

```
public class HomeController : MyBaseController
```

Then in your master page, loop through the ViewData["menu"]:

```
<% foreach (MenuClass in ViewData["menu"]) { %>
<li>
    <%=Html.RouteLink(MenuClass.LinkTitle, new { controller = "Home", action = MenuClass.Action }) %>
</li>
<% } %>
```

Note: this is all from scratch, so there may be errors, but this is what I did on my last MVC project.

Comment: My Menu is an HTMLExtension that I wrote to get menu items out of the database, loops through them and then just returns an HTML Unordered list to the page.  How would I modify it to do ActionLink/RouteLinks and then output the unordered list?

Comment: Its ok I have amended my Menu extension so instead of <li><a href="/news">News</a></li> I have got <li> + helper.RouteLink(urlTitle, new { controller = "WebPage", action = "Details", pageName = linkUrl }) +</li>.  What is the difference between this approach and using ActionLink?

Comment: ActionLink directs you to an action in the same controller (unless you specify the controller in the parameters).  RouteLink makes you choose the route (controller, action, id).

Answer (score 0):

How are those links in the MasterPage defined? If they link to 'news', you should use '/news' and '/homepage', or else it will append it to current url (in your case, /error).